# Verify 2 cookies with mod_rewrite before serving images

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, cookie

I have the following mod_rewrite rule, which works fine in my Apache 2.x on CentOS 6 Linux machine, but it is not complete:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !id
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sites/default/files/pictures/picture-
RewriteRule .* /images/dummy.png [L]
```

because I'm trying to change it in 2 ways:

1. Actually 2 cookies (and not just 1 as above) should be present: **id** and **auth** (but I don't know, how to do **(X or Y) and Z** with mod_rewrite)
2. I'd like to verify that the value of the **auth** cookie is a 32 hex chars string (an MD5 hash) and that the value of **id** cookie is numeric.

The background is that I've gotten a bill for EUR 1000,- from Getty
Images, because one of the Drupal users on my server has supposedly used their picture as an avatar. I'm not looking for any lawyer or pseudo-lawyer advice here, just for the way to display a dummy image instead of real user pictures to web crawlers.

And yes, I've noticed in [the mod_rewrite doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), that I could pass the cookie values to an external script through mod_rewrite (for verifying the MD5 hash), but I'd like to tackle this later.

**UPDATE 2:**

I've come up with the following

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sites/default/files/pictures/picture-
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !auth=[a-fA-F0-9]{32} [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !id=[0-9]+
RewriteRule .* /images/dummy.png [L]
```

but I'm not sure, if the above `RewriteCond`'s act as **X and (Y or Z)** or **(X and Y) or Z**

Comment: Instead of specifying `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ...` it is more efficient to specify this URL pattern in the `RewriteRule` _pattern_. The `RewriteRule` is processed first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(^|;\s*)id=[0-9]+(;\s*)auth=[0-9a-fA-F]{32}(;\s*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sites/default/files/pictures/picture-
RewriteRule .* /images/dummy.png [L]
```

Comment: Does this cover if "auth=" is in front of "id="?  And is maybe \b better here, than (^|;) ? But I get your idea, thanks...

Comment: If the "auth" arrives in the cookie first (i.e. before "id") your rule won't work.

Comment: A workaround (if you control the setting of the cookie) is to combine the values into one cookie `foo=id:auth;` and then parse out `id` and `auth`.

Comment: @AlexanderFarber "is maybe `\b` better here, than `(^|;\s*)`" - Generally, no. If, for example, you had another cookie of the form `something-id` then this will erroneously satisfy your test when the required `id` cookie is not present.

Answer (score 3):

> but I'm not sure, if the above RewriteCond's act as **X and (Y or Z)** or **(X and Y) or Z**

In the directives you posted it is the former: **X and (Y or Z)**

However, as mentioned in my comment above, it is more efficient to do the URL-path check in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* - since this is what's processed first. This avoids the `RewriteRule` being processed for every request (as is what happens when using a catch-all pattern like `.*`). You then have just two `OR`d conditions that check the absence of either cookie (in any order). For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(^|;\s*)id=[0-9]+ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(^|;\s*)auth=[0-9a-f]{32}
RewriteRule ^/?sites/default/files/pictures/picture- /images/dummy.png [L]
```

The `(^|;\s*)` pattern prefix before the cookie name is just to safeguard against the situation when you have other cookies with a similar (but longer) name. eg. `uid` or `userauth`, etc. If that is not possible then this subpattern could be omitted.

`[0-9a-fA-F]{32}` - The result of an md5 hash is usually always lowercase, it's certainly never mixed case, so checking for `a-f` *and* `A-F` is unnecessary.

There is no need to check for `(;\s*)` at the end of the cookie value, as in @quanta's answer, since this is not part of the value you are trying to validate. And the `Cookie:` header is not expected to end with a `;` anyway - so this may not even match.